# passing and escaping aposthrope or single quote in document.createTextNode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to createTextNode of a string containing an aposthrope/single quote. But it always fail. Here is my sample code:

```
var theText= "John's car";
var str = "var par= document.createElement('p');";
str += "par.style.textAlign='left';";
str += "var fnt= document.createElement('font');";
str += "var txt = document.createTextNode('" + theText  + "');";
str += "fnt.appendChild(txt);";
str += "par.appendChild(fnt);";
str += myDiv + ".appendChild(par);";
eval(str);
```

Comment: That looks like trouble... Why do you need to eval it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you have an `'` inside a string, replace it with a `\'` and everything should work fine. Your first line, for example, should be changed from this:

```
var theText= "John's car";
```

To this:

```
var theText= "John\'s car";
```

Comment: I change theText to : "John \'s car", then I add a function to replace the content of the Text, theText = theText.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').replace(/'/g, "\\'");

Answer (score 3):

Erm... Why on earth are you doing that?

```
var theText= "John's car";
var par= document.createElement('p');
par.style.textAlign='left';
par.appendChild(document.createTextNode(theText));
myDiv.appendChild(par);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain the ' in John's car, its as simple as John\'s car
or ('p') would be (\'p\')

Comment: thanks..but that doesnt work in my case unless i put additional stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use functions instead *eval*. That would solve a lot of issues:

```
function addNode(myText, myDiv) {
  par= document.createElement('p');
  par.style.textAlign='left';
  fnt= document.createElement('font'); // font is not supported in HTML 5. Use CSS styles instead.
  txt = document.createTextNode(myText);
  fnt.appendChild(txt);
  par.appendChild(fnt);
  myDiv.appendChild(par);
}

addNode ("John's car", targetDiv);
```